# The concept about jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was a beginner in JavaScript and jQuery.

here is my question

```
var a = $("selector").height(); // or other methods
```

if I would like to change the height of this element to "b"

why should I write the `$("selector").height("b");` instead of "a = b"??

Comment: Because `height()` is a function, and the same time, we can say it's a property when no value passed.

Comment: *I was a beginner in JavaScript and jQuery* - and then what happened?

Comment: in most of jquery, `something.foo()` returns the current value(s) of whatever `foo` is, while `something.foo(bar)` sets the value of `foo` to `bar`.

Comment: @Amit Perhaps he took an `->` to the knee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because b has to be attached to a jQuery object ($) in order to manipulate it in the DOM. making a = b simply equates the values. It does nothing to the DOM itself. You also need to remove the quotes from the "b" variable - otherwise you are passing the string "b" instead of the variable itself.

```
var b = 100;
$("selector").height(b);
```

Comment: This is not valid code.  `var b=100px` is not valid.  EDIT:  now it is after you have edited it.

Comment: you updated your answer, it was not valid before the edit.

Comment: I tried to ninja edit it after I realized I left the px on the 100. Thank you for catching it.

Answer (score 5):

That's the difference between setters and getters, as another programming language.

`$(selector).height()` returns the height of `selector`, so is a getter.

`$(selector).height("90")` sets a height of 90px, so is a setter.

When you make `var a = $(selector).height()` you are storing the height of the `selector` to the `a` variable.

Comment: Your answer made me understand the question, it seemed like utter non-sense to me before, thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you write `var a = $("selector").height();`, you are assigning the value of the height method call to the variable `a`.

You are not in any way creating a link to the actual height via the variable `a`.  This is why you cannot say `a=100` where 100 is the new height.

You must use the method call `$("selector").height(a)`, where `a` is a variable containing the numerical value of the height you require.

Answer (score 1):

[The $.fn.height method](http://api.jquery.com/height/) without any arguments is a getter that will return a number. You can add or subtract that number to your hearts content but it wont get you anywhere.

When you pass an argument it becomes a setter that will actually change the selected element.